# Copy a .txt file with a variable in the title to another folder

Tags: powershell

I have a simple ping script that produces an output file at the end to a local folder, the file name contains a variable that pulls the host name of the computer its run on and adds it to the file name. I then want to be able to move this file to another file path but wasn't how to do with the variable names .txt file.

```
$H = hostname 

cd c:/users 

ping ipaddress -n 4 |Foreach{"{0} - {1}" -f (Get-Date),$_} > chosenfolder\$H"DC1!".txt
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Tried using the basic copy-item cmdlet but this didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you are after is to move the file then you can you the `mv` command in powershell.

```
$H = hostname 

cd c:/users 

ping ipaddress -n 4 |Foreach{"{0} - {1}" -f (Get-Date),$_} > chosenfolder\$H"DC1!".txt

mv chosenfolder\$H"DC1!".txt C:\<whatever path>
```

Comment: Nice, Thanks would this have to change if it was a network drive I wanted to move the file to?

Comment: As long as you fully qualify the target destination, you should be good to go.